# How would I purge/drop rows that have repeating values across columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how I would drop rows in a pandas dataframe that have repeating values across columns.

I searched around and found most answers were using `df.drop_duplicates()`, though I don't think that applies here, since I'm looking column-wise and not row-wise.

Ex DF:

```
| user_a | user_b |
|--------|--------|
|   103  |   241  |
|   512  |   512  | 
|   402  |   253  |
```

Here's a portion of something I would be working with, two account numbers compared to one another, I would want to keep the rows that do not have the same number in the **user_a** and the **user_b** columns, and remove the rows with the same number.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply compare `user_a` and `user_b` row-wise.

```
df.loc[df['user_a'] != df['user_b']]  # OR df.loc[df['user_a'].ne(df['user_b'])]
```

Output:

```
    user_a  user_b
0   103     241
2   402     253
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the OP you can use [`df.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) over `axis=1` and compare with [`not equals`](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&ei=RpFVXZa-JYfXvATx_oGgAQ&q=series+ne&oq=series+ne&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0l9.290.1033..1367...0.0..0.101.459.4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i20i263.ZQVGo9RhjUw&ved=0ahUKEwiW-e6_roXkAhWHK48KHXF_ABQQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) 1:

```
df[df.nunique(1).ne(1)]
```

---

```
   user_a  user_b
0     103     241
2     402     253
```